# Fender frontman G10 amp or any other 2.1 channel speaker with Zoom G1on processor?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, effects-pedal

I had bought a "Zoom G1on" processor with my "Jackson Dinky js12" guitar.
It sounds okay with any other speaker but should I consider using a "Fender frontman G10" amp too?

Will it sound any different than the speakers? Any other reason why I should be using the amp instead of the speakers?

Explanations appreciated. I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The G1on is a small multi-effect unit which has guitar effects and amp/speaker simulations.

If you plug that unit into a guitar amp (such as a Fender Frontman), you then have to take into account the voicing of that specific amp - so the amp/speaker simulations in the unit won't actually sound like the amp/speakers that they're meant to simulate. If you plug the unit into a standard PA, the amp/speaker simulations will sound more like Zoom intended them to (may or may not be similar to the device they're trying to simulate...)

In summary; it's your choice. But if you need to buy the new Fender amp, I'd say just use whatever you have at hand until you get more familiar with the unit and the guitar - save yourself some money in the short-term.

Comment: So what I can understand is, if I only had the fender frontman, it would be a good investment but since I have the processor already, I don't really need another amplifier. Monitor speakers would be a better investment as they would make it sound more like the processor intends it to.

Comment: Earlier I had tried connecting the processor output to my home sound system (4.1 channel speakers) but it felt like it didn't really sound like it did while I was playing it in the guitar shop before buying it. Hopefully monitor speakers will sound different.

Comment: Home sound systems are voiced differently from PA's, and guitar amps are voiced differently again.